# Mongodb fetch record in sub document using filter

Tags: node.js, mongodb, database

In the following records I want to get item_details where type is "**system**" and id is "**7634e9639f5c25f2434b72d8a**"

```
var operator = {
        'item_details': {
            $elemMatch: {
                type: 'custom'
            }
        }           
    }

   var query = {
   _id : "7634e9639f5c25f2434b72d8a"
   };

   req.db.collection('products').find(query, operator).toArray(function (err, result) {

   if(err)throw err;
   console.log(result);
});
```

It is returning only the first element. But need to get the all records which matches the query and projection. **Below is the sample data from which I want to query.**

```
        [
        {

            "_id": "7634e9639f5c25f2434b72d8a",
            "item_details": [
                {

                    "quantity": 1,
                    "sub_total": 1201,
                    "type": "system"
                },
                {
                    "quantity": 19,
                    "sub_total": 140,
                    "type": "custom"

                },
                {
                    "quantity": 81,
                    "sub_total": 130,
                    "type": "custom"

                },
                {
                    "quantity": 71,
                    "sub_total": 90,
                    "type": "system"

                }
            ]

        },

        {

            "_id": "564e9639f5c25f2434b72d8a",
            "item_details": [
                {

                    "quantity": 1,
                    "sub_total": 101,
                    "type": "system"
                },
                {
                    "quantity": 9,
                    "sub_total": 40,
                    "type": "custom"

                },
                {
                    "quantity": 8,
                    "sub_total": 30,
                    "type": "custom"

                },
                {
                    "quantity": 7,
                    "sub_total": 60,
                    "type": "system"

                }
            ]

        }
    ]
```

Answer (score 1):

$elemmatch will only give you the 1st element of the array (in subdocuments).
see below
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/

So we could rather use the dot notation to get what you want.

```
req.db.collection('products').find({"_id": "7634e9639f5c25f2434b72d8a", "item_details.type": "custom"}).toArray(function(err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result);
});
```